# Creating a repeatable mapping in Vim

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings

I find myself often aligning certain code blocks by inserting one or more spaces, like in the following situation:

```
case something of
    Just a▉-> ...
    Nothing -> ...
```

Here `▉` is the position of my cursor. In order to align the arrows, I enter insert mode with `i`, hit `<Space>` and `<Esc>`. In my vim configuration the `<Space>` key doesn't do anything meaningful, so I tried creating the following mapping, hoping that it would do the same job with just one keystroke:

```
nnoremap <Space> i<Space><Esc>
```

In case of one space character this works without any problems, and even repeating with `.` works. However, `3<Space>` won't insert 3 spaces without moving the cursor. With the help of this [Vim Tips wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_2)#Supplying_a_count_to_a_map) article, I made the following mapping:

```
nnoremap <Space> @="i\<lt>Space>\<lt>Esc>"<CR>
```

This successfully inserts `n` number of spaces with `n<Space>`, but the problem is that I cannot repeat `n<Space>` with `.`. I would like to make this repeatable in a way, that when I first insert 2 spaces with `2<Space>` and hit the repeat operation `.`, it would insert 2 spaces again instead of one.

My knowledge of Vimscript is very limited, but I suppose one could write such mapping with help of a function, and use a plugin like [repeat](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) to do the repetition part? Or is this possible to do without any plugins?

Comment: To clarify: you wish for `.` to use the last count with your mapping?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry, my explanation is probably not the best. English is not my first language. :)

Comment: No your explanation is actually quite good—I just want to make sure answers focus on the right part

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create repeatable mappings by passing them through `g@`.

```
function! s:insspace(...)
  if a:0
    " perform operation
    execute 'normal' v:count1.'i '."\<esc>".'`['
  else
    " set up
    let &operatorfunc = matchstr(expand('<sfile>'), '[^. ]*$')
    return "g@\<space>"
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent><expr> <space> <sid>insspace()
```

Normally `g@` is used for operators, but by using `g@<space>`, this makes it an actual operation.  The function here `s:insspace` actually called twice, once with no arguments meaning "set up," which sets the `operatorfunc` option to itself (the complicated-looking `matchstr`), and again by vim with one argument (see `:help g@`).

This approach is general.  To use a different operation you only need to change the line after the comment "perform operation."

Answer (score 1):

You could use `` `[ `` to return "to the first character of the previously changed or yanked text" (from `` :help `[ ``)

```
nnoremap <Space> i<Space><esc>`[
```

This works with `<Space>` and `3<Space>`.

Flaw: If you do `3<Space>` and you want to add another three spaces with `.`, the cursor will move. From my understanding, this is because with `.` Vim repeats the change (inserting 3 spaces), but not the mapping. A following `` `[ `` will bring the cursor back to the initial position.

Comment: This is a operates the same as my solution, but is simpler and more elegant. However, what I really want is the repeat operation `.` to work as I mentioned. :/