# Repeat/copy a character sequence using commands

Tags: key-bindings

I tried the following in my `.vimrc` using the hints I found [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19070/6370):

```
map <Tab> i4<Space><Esc>
map <F2> /79*<CR>79*/<CR>PROGRAM<Space>NAME<Space><Space><Space><Space>:
```

The first mapping inserts a `4` while the behavior that I expected is to insert 4 whitespaces characters.

And the second one throws the following error:

```
E486: Pattern not found: 79*
```

while I expected it to produce the following line:

```
/*******************************************************************************
PROGRAM NAME    :
```

Is there something up there that I'm doing wrong or there's something I'm missing here?

Comment: You should point what you expect to get by _both_ of this mappings (preferably, not as VimScript comments, because _comments are not allowed after map_) The first one must be `4i` not `i4`; the second one, I can't even guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry about that. Should have added it to make things clear. Just did that now.

Comment: For the second mapping what it currently does: 1. search for 79(9), then 2. search for 79th occurence of current word under cursor, then 3. search again for previous search, then pasting, replacing and whatever should happen when you try enter PROGRAM in normal mode.

Comment: Just to let you know, in vim there is `>>` and `<<` used to indent and dedent the line. You don't have to explicitly insert spaces like that. `:nnoremap <tab> >>` should work for you. What would be inserted (spaces or tab) depends on `expandtab` option.

Comment: @MaximKim Wow. That's very nice. I'm new to vim and am overwhelmed by the options I have. And a bit confused too. Hehehe. I'll get the hang of it as I use it more I guess.

Comment: I would suggest to use `>` and `<` normal commands. They work in visual mode and with text objects. Put your cursor on a paragraph and press `>ip`, it would indend whole paragraph. Then press `.` which would repeat previous operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one, exchange `i` and `4`:

```
nnoremap <Tab> 4i<Space><Esc> " inserts 4 space characters
```

`i` starts insert mode and whatever you "type" is inserted into text. If you pass `count` before `i`, whatever you type afterwards would be repeated `count` times.

For the second one -- not sure what it is supposed to do.

**EDIT**
For the second one:

```
nnoremap <F2> i/<esc>79a*<esc>oPROGRAM NAME    :<esc>
```

1. `i/<esc>` -- insert `/`
2. `79a*<esc>` -- add 79 stars
3. `oPROGRAM NAME    :<esc>` -- `o`pen new line and insert `PROGRAM NAME    :`

**PS**

better use `nnoremap` instead of `map` as it is more specific for normal mode and it uses no remapped key sequences (imagine you have remapped `i` and `o` and other used keys to smth else...)

**PPS**

I personally would go with functions, like

```
func! CstyleHeader()
    let stars = repeat('*', 79)
    let lines = ['/' . stars, 'PROGRAM NAME    :', stars . '/']
    call append('.', lines)
endfunc
map <F2> :call CstyleHeader()<CR>
```

Comment: The second line is basically like a program header that I would like to print at the top of the source file - a C comment starting with `/*` followed by 78 `*`s and a `PROGRAM NAME` in the next line.

Comment: I have noticed that you completely discarded `<CR>` in your answer. Any specific reason for replacing `<CR>` with `o` for new line charactrer? Aren't they the same things?

Comment: To use `<CR>` for newline I should be in insert mode. If I "connect" it with previous `79a*<CR>` it would insert 79 stars and newlines. So I should either make it as `79a*<esc>a<CR>` or just `79a*<esc>o`

Comment: Got it. Makes sense.