# Repeat a mapping (like a macro) with dot

Tags: repeated-commands

There seems to be quite a few questions around `g@`, its quite a confusing topic. And I can't get it to work.

I created these two mappings to edit a line from python dictionary form to variable assignment form, and back (so to switch between these two lines):

```python
  'foo' : 'bar',      
  foo = 'bar'
```

Heres the mappings:

```
" Python variable to dict
nnoremap <leader>{ I'<ESC>ea'<ESC>f=r:A,<ESC>j
" Python dict to variable
nnoremap <leader>= ^xelxf:r=$xj
```

It works great, however often one wishes to run it multiple times, so I would like it to repeat with the dot operator:

I tried to follow https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_2)#Supplying_a_count_to_a_map

```
" Python variable to dict
nmap <leader>{ @g="I'<C-V><ESC>ea'<C-V><ESC>f=r:A,<C-V><ESC>j"<CR>

" Python dict to variable
nmap <leader>= @g='^xelxf:r=$xj'<CR>
```

But its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works:

```
" Python variable to dict
nmap <leader>{ @="I'<C-V><ESC>ea'<C-V><ESC>f=r:A,<C-V><ESC>j"<CR>

" Python dict to variable
nmap <leader>= @='^xelxf:r=$xj'<CR>
```

You seem to have added a `g` after the `@`. That was causing the problem.

**UPDATE**: From this [SO answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19071/16280)

To get a dot-repeatable mapping, use this function.

```
function! s:var2dict(...)
  if a:0
    " perform operation
    " let save_cursor = getcurpos()
    execute "normal! I'\<ESC>ea'\<ESC>f=r:A,\<ESC>j^"
    " call setpos('.', save_cursor)
    " unlet save_cursor
  else
    " set up
    let &operatorfunc = matchstr(expand('<sfile>'), '[^. ]*$')
    echom &operatorfunc
    return "g@\<space>"
  endif
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> <leader>{ <sid>var2dict()
```

The function uses `:h operatorfunc` to set this mapping as the operation to perform the next time DOT is pressed. More detailed explanation is given at the  [SO answer linked here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19071/16280)

This function does not (yet) support counts.

Comment: Good find! Although it now works the first time, it's no better than the orginal version in that if I press '.' (dot), it does not repeat the operations, it just repeats the last 'x' (delete char).

Comment: Right. Because you're only mapping (simulating) a repeatable action. Vim itself is not seeing it as a discrete action. Interesting use case. I remember reading about a solution somewhere. Lemme see if I can find it.

Comment: @run_the_race, tpope to the rescue. http://vimcasts.org/episodes/creating-repeatable-mappings-with-repeat-vim/

Comment: @run_the_race, updated the answer

Comment: working brilliantly, well done!